# Error Issuing certificate for wildcard dns name for kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, cert-manager

I'm trying to use `wildcard` on kubernetes. But i have not success.
My idea is configure wildcard, so my application to use dynamic subdomains. I'm doing that locally, but when i tried to do deploy i got this problem. I'm using Digital Ocean Cluster.

I configured my k8s file like that.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: myemail@mycompany.com.br
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: apps
  name: menu-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: menu
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: menu
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: menu
          image: company/company-menu:$VERSION
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: VERSION
              value: $VERSION

      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: hub
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: apps
  name: menu-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: menu
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: apps
  name: menu-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - menu.mydomain.dev
        - '*.menu.mydomain.dev'
      secretName: menuwild-tls
  rules:
    - host: menu.mydomain.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: menu-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

But i'm getting this

```
menuwild-tls       False   menuwild-tls       27m
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing works

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, you cannot issue certificates for wildcard DNS names using `HTTP-01` acme-challenge. You need to prove a *stronger challenge*. You need `DNS-01` challenge setup which in turn creates some DNS records to validate your authority of the DNS name. For that cert-manager needs your DNS server access to do some authorized REST calls.

You need to get an access token from the digital ocean and create a secret named `digitalocean-dns` with data key `access-token` and refer to it in the `Issuer` config as below. Have a look at the [docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/digitalocean/) too.

#### Issuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-digital-ocean-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: user@abc.org
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-cloudlfare-prod
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        digitalocean:
          tokenSecretRef:
            name: digitalocean-dns
            key: access-token
```

#### Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-digital-ocean-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: test-ing
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: '*.menu.mydomain.dev'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.menu.mydomain.dev'
    secretName: wild-menu-tls
```

When you debug it, check the logs of cert-manager pods:

```
k logs -f cert-manager-3f43v34f34-fg3 -n cert-manager
```

If you check `Certificate` status, they are not getting updated with the errors.

NOTE:
You also need two `DNS` `A` records for your Load Balancer IP for names `menu` and `*.menu`.

I have validated this in a real environment. Let me know if you need further guidance.

Comment: @Rafael Augusto, check this out !!

Comment: I'm not using cloudflare. My DNS is manager for Digital Ocean, and my cluster is in Digital Ocean too.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto, use the guide here for DigitalOcean dns provider - https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/digitalocean/